# Python list constructor using reference to another list

Tags: python, list, constructor, reference

I specified node[0][2] as node[1], and later on modified node[1], but node[0][2] is still [] in the print out. How do I pass the reference of node[1] in constructing node[0]?

```
node=[[] for i in range(5)]
node[0]=['d', 'Test Market', node[1], "Don't test market", node[2]]
node[1]=['e', 'Local success', 0.6, node[3], 'Local Failure', 0.4, node[4]]
node[2]=['t', 23]
node[3]=['t', 45]
node[4]=['t', 12]
print node

[['d', 'Test Market', [], "Don't test market", []], ['e', 'Local success', 0.6, [], 'Local Failure', 0.4, []], ['t', 23], ['t', 45], ['t', 12]]
```

````

Comment: did you try just change the order of the assignments.  node[1] before node[0].

Comment: For my application it is natural to record nodes sequentially. The answer from Joran works and explains!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
node[2][:] = ['t',23]
```

the reason being is that

```
node[2] = [1,2,...]
```

overwrites the value at `node[2]`

whereas

```
node[2][:] = [1,2,...]
```

fills the existing array at node[2] (overly simplified but meh)

this may help you visualize the process [Visualization](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=a+%3D+%5B%5B%5D,%5B%5D,%5B%5D,%5B%5D%5D%0Aa%5B1%5D+%3D+%5B1,2,3,a%5B2%5D,a%5B3%5D%5D%0Aa%5B2%5D+%3D+%5B2,3%5D%0Aa%5B3%5D%5B%3A%5D+%3D+%5B4,5%5D%0Aprint+a&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&cumulative=false&heapPrimitives=false&textReferences=false&py=2&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&curInstr=4)